# how to set ng-select to correct value from record?

Tags: angularjs

stack: angular, mongoose,node
we have two models, one is qualifications (id and name) and one is user (several properties but also object reference to qualification.

```
qualification: {type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Qualification'}
```

in our angular view, before rendering we use $http to load the selected user from backend and show the different input fields.
we wanna show also the possible qualifications in a drop down list and make sure the currently assigned is selected.

In this snippet you see:
1° {{user.qualification}} is correctly displaying the id of the selected qualification as stored in mongo
2° the drop down list populates correctly
3° if i change the value of the dropdownlist by selecting one, it is updated in the

tag
4° if i call my save method in this form the selected value is saved in mongo

the only thing that isn't working is that the initial state of the drop down list is set to the current user qualification.

```
 <p>{{user.qualification}}</p>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label   class="col-md-2 control-label">Qualification</label>
                <div class="col-md-2" >

                    <select data-ng-model="user.qualification"
                            name = "user.qualification"
                            data-ng-options="qual._id for qual in qualifications">

                    </select>


                </div>
            </div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.findOneUser = function() {

            $http.get('/administration/showuser/'+$stateParams.userID)
                .success(function(data){
                    $scope.user = data;
                         $scope.fetchQualifications();
                })
                .error(function(data){
                    alert('error');
                });
        };
$scope.fetchQualifications = function() {
            $http.get('/administration/qualifications')
                .success(function(data){
                    $scope.qualifications = data;
                })
                .error(function(data){
                    alert('error');
                });
        };
```

**View**

```
<section data-ng-controller="AdministrationController" data-ng-init="findOneUser()"  >
    <h3>Edit User{{user._id}}</h3>

    <form class="form-horizontal col-md-12" role="form" data-ng-submit="updateUser()">
        <!-- LEFT -->
        <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label  for="firstName" class="col-md-2 control-label">FirstName</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.profile.personal.firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="Firstame" >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label  for="lastName" class="col-md-2 control-label">Lastname</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.profile.personal.lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Lastname" >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label  for="mobile" class="col-md-2 control-label">Mobile</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.profile.contact.mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label  for="phone" class="col-md-2 control-label">Phone</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.profile.contact.phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label  for="featured" class="col-md-2 control-label">Featured</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.featuredArtist" data-ng-checked="user.featuredArtist" id="featured"   >
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <!-- RIGHT -->
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  for="street" class="col-md-2 control-label">Street</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.profile.address.street" id="street" placeholder="Street" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  for="postalCode" class="col-md-2 control-label">Postal code</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.profile.address.postalCode" id="postalCode" placeholder="Postal code" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  for="city" class="col-md-2 control-label">City</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.profile.address.city" id="city" placeholder="City" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  for="state" class="col-md-2 control-label">State</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.profile.address.state" id="state" placeholder="State" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label  for="blocked" class="col-md-2 control-label">Blocked</label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.blocked" data-ng-checked="user.blocked" id="blocked"   >
                </div>
            </div>
            **<p>{{user.qualification}}</p>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label   class="col-md-2 control-label">Qualification</label>
                <div class="col-md-2" >

                    <select data-ng-model="user.qualification"
                            name = "user.qualification"
                            data-ng-options="qual._id for qual in qualifications">

                    </select>


                </div>
            </div>**



        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancelUser()">Cancel</button>
            </div>


        </div>
    </form>



</section>
```

Comment: What should the initial state of the dropdown be?

Comment: the value that is stored in user.qualification. eg. in mongo the following qualifications are there. Default, Professional, Private, Public i have a user named Peter with a qualification Professional so when i want to edit this user (in this sample) the drop down list should have Professional selected, since that is the current state

Comment: Could your provide a JSFiddle please?

Comment: it's completely integrated in a multi module application. I'll edit the post with more info

Comment: this is the part not setting it correctly  <select data-ng-model="user.qualification"
                            name = "user.qualification"
                            data-ng-options="qual._id for qual in qualifications">

                    </select>

Comment: @SamP do you know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `user.qualification` needs to match a `qual._id`. Is that true here?

Comment: user.qualification holds the object Id from the model qualification: {type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Qualification'} and if it matches the qual._id it should be selected